# Auto-post or share on facebook from my own blog/article/listing platform

Tags: facebook, post

I have been searching for a way to automatically post or share articles / listings from my own self-made blog-ish platform. It's nothing complicated and every article/listing contains a title, category, content, tags, images, and contact information.

The question has been if its possible to automatically share every new post as it is made, to facebook without having to do this manually, or write a new post on Facebook altogether with the given content. After searching quite thoroughly I cant find a solution to this problem, does anyone have any good suggestions?

PS: All of the posts/articles/listings from my platform are stored in a MySQL database and are accessed from there to display them on my site.

Comment: The easiest thing to do, other than hitting the Facebook API yourself when you publish, is probably to create an RSS feed and hook it into IFTTT. Tell IFTTT to post all new articles to Facebook, Twitter, whatever... There are other services that will push feeds as well besides IFTTT.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Going directly for the FB api was an option but I wasnt quite sure its allowed. I will look into this IFTTT :)